# Using rigged in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

**Context**: Someone swipes a card at an ATM machine and withdraws money. Sometime later, some money got deducted from the account because, in the area where the card is inserted, the thief must have placed some hidden scanner there to fetch the card details, etc... in addition to having a camera which is recording the buttons pressed by the person
Can one say that the **ATM was rigged**?
Is that a correct usage of the word rigged?
Any other words to express this succinctly?

Comment: With an actual computer, we'd normally say it was ***infected*** (by a virus, or malware of some kind). But with something like an ATM, ***compromised*** or ***tampered with*** is more likely (whatever was done to it could be more "physical" than simply introducing "malware").

Comment: *Rigged* doesn't sound quite right here.  We say that a game is rigged, to mean "set up unfairly, so that the outcome is predetermined", but it doesn't quite work with a machine.

Comment: @stangdon didn't Donald Trump and his allies use allegations about 'rigged voting machines' to try to overturn the result of the 2020 US presidential election? Aren't slot machines in casinos widely believed to often be 'rigged'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: The OP hasn't responded to my request for clarification, but most likely whatever's been done to the ATM is specifically in order to ***steal*** someone's money (to facilitate ***theft***). I agree with stangdon that "rigged" doesn't really seem the right word *if that is indeed the situation.* (But we don't *know*, yet! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I mean that in the area where the card is inserted, the thief must have placed some hidden scanner there to fetch the card details, etc... in addition to having a camera which is recording the buttons pressed by the person

Comment: You're supposed to edit that explanation into your question. Comments are only supposed to be used by us to request clarification, and *in principle* the moderators may just delete them once they've served their purpose.

Comment: Three conmen who swiped £9,000 from a rigged cashpoint were convicted yesterday. The trio set an ATM at a village service station to pay out 10 times the cash customers demanded. But they were rumbled after they failed to reset it - and honest motorists benefitted. One driver, who asked for £100, was amazed when £1,000 in £20 notes spilled out. _Daily Mirror_ (UK) 4 Feb 2012

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: As I remembered that event (or perhaps there were several different ones), the ATM simply malfunctionned and doled out much more money than *any* user asked for - but as soon as the first user checked his remaining balance and saw it had only gone down by the amount requested rather than what had been delivered, he told everyone else, and the whole village queued up to withdraw funds until the ATM ran out of cash. If thieves had been able to tamper with the machine to make that happen, and then reset it, it would be obvious who did it because *they'd* have to make a withdrawal

Comment: @FumbleFingers - there have been plenty of occasions where machines malfunctioned and people piled in, but the one in the Daily Mirror story involved a criminal logging in to the machine with a 'secret password' and reprogramming it, as the [Surrey Live story](https://www.getsurrey.co.uk/news/local-news/men-jailed-over-cash-machine-4819460) clarified.

Comment: Where do people 'swipe' cards to use ATMs?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - It wouldn't surprise me if that was the US. They are really decades behind on electronic money-handling, they're struggling to make chip & PIN a standard, let alone NFC. People still use cheques.

Comment: Oh, not this nonsense again.  I realize Europeans love to think the US is all stone knives and bearskins, but they don't know what they're talking about.  We are not "struggling to make chip & PIN a standard": we started using chip & signature decades ago and never bothered with chip & PIN.  Lots of places use NFC.  About 95% of Americans are paid via electronic direct deposit and most stores don't accept checks anymore.

Comment: @stangdon - sorry, but that's still just playing catch up. Signature went out the window here 20 years or more ago, chip & PIN became compulsory in 2006. Cards do still have mag strips too, but they are being removed from next year. You haven't been able to pay by cheque for about 15 years. Many places, including public transport **only** accept NFC. Even the homeless guys selling The Big Issue on street corners have NFC/chip & PIN readers because fewer & fewer people carry cash any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "rig" a device means to alter it to operate in a particular way, often not the way it was intended to operate. Whether adding a scanner and camera to an ATM counts as "rigging" depends on how strict you feel like being with that definition.

On the one side, if you put a scanner device inside an ATM and it doesn't interfere with the normal operation of the ATM, then you're not altering the way the ATM itself operates, just like putting a camera outside an ATM doesn't alter how the ATM operates. So from this perspective, no, "rigged" isn't appropriate.

On the other side, people tend to consider "a device" to be whatever's inside the box, so if you add a separate device to an ATM's box that adds unwanted behaviour to the box, people would commonly say the ATM is "rigged", even if the ATM device itself was operating as normal.

The story Michael Harvey put in a comment about thieves altering an ATM to dispense 10x the requested amount of cash definitely involves "rigging" the ATM because the thieves altered the behaviour of the ATM itself, rather than merely adding some monitoring devices.

As for words that are unambiguous, you could say the ATM was "*tampered with*" or "*modified*".

Comment: One of those relatively rare occasions where comments usefully provide the raw material for defining the applicability limits of a usage. But although you've very nicely set out exactly why "rigged" doesn't quite fit the OP's context, you haven't suggested any different terms that *do* fit the context. I can't think of anything better than ***tampered with*** myself. For an expression the general public might use, I mean - ***compromised*** sounds a bit like "corporate / official vocabulary" such as might be used in the bank's fraud detection department, or the legal system.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. Addded

Comment: Actually, I think the exact process OP describes can be referred to as [***skimming** ATMs*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/skimming), but I'm not sure how idiomatic it is to say *the ATM was skimmed*. I'd more likely say the *victim* was skimmed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "skimming" seems to be the action the device or thief does, not what has happened to the ATM, so it seems relevant, but tangential to the OP's actual question about rigging/tampering.

Comment: Indeed. But the OP has also asked for *other words to express this succinctly*, where "this" doesn't necessarily mean *please provide more words that can be used in the construction **The ATM was XXXX'ed.***